# How to find all the Xpaths of the text in html code

Tags: html, python-3.x, lxml

I have scraped my own website [www.biteloop.in](http://www.biteloop.in) (my own) and now I want to find full Xpath of all the text in that html code.

Sample HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Complex HTML Code</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header id="header" class="main-header">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Welcome to the Complex HTML Page</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section id="content" class="main-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h2>About Us</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h2>Our Services</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Web Design</li>
                        <li>Graphic Design</li>
                        <li>Content Writing</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <footer id="footer" class="main-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h3>Contact Info</h3>
                    <p>1234 Main Street, City, Country</p>
                    <p>Phone: 123-456-7890</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h3>Follow Us</h3>
                    <ul class="social-links">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h3>Newsletter</h3>
                    <form action="#" method="post">
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
                        <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Code:

```
from lxml import etree

def get_element_xpath(element):
    xpath = ''
    while element is not None:
        parent = element.getparent()
        if parent is not None:
            index = parent.index(element) + 1
            if index != 1:
                xpath = f"/{element.tag}[{index}]{xpath}"
            else:
                xpath = f"/{element.tag}{xpath}"
        element = parent
    return '/' + xpath

def get_element_text(element):
    text = element.text.strip() if element.text else ''
    return text

# Parse the HTML code
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.fromstring(html_code, parser)

# Retrieve all elements
elements = tree.xpath("//*")
element_xpath_text = []
for element in elements:
    xpath = get_element_xpath(element)
    text = get_element_text(element)
    element_xpath_text.append((xpath, text))

# Print the XPaths and associated text
for xpath, text in element_xpath_text:
    print(f"XPath: {xpath}")
    print(f"Text: {text}")
    print()
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
XPath: /
Text: 

XPath: //head
Text: 

XPath: //head/meta
Text: 

XPath: //head/title[2]
Text: Complex HTML Code

XPath: //body[2]
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/header
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/header/div
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/header/div/h1
Text: Welcome to the Complex HTML Page

XPath: //body[2]/header/div/nav[2]
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/header/div/nav[2]/ul
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/header/div/nav[2]/ul/li
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/header/div/nav[2]/ul/li/a
Text: Home

XPath: //body[2]/header/div/nav[2]/ul/li[2]
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/header/div/nav[2]/ul/li[2]/a
Text: About

XPath: //body[2]/header/div/nav[2]/ul/li[3]
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/header/div/nav[2]/ul/li[3]/a
Text: Services

XPath: //body[2]/header/div/nav[2]/ul/li[4]
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/header/div/nav[2]/ul/li[4]/a
Text: Contact

XPath: //body[2]/section[2]
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/section[2]/div
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/section[2]/div/div
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/section[2]/div/div/div
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/section[2]/div/div/div/h2
Text: About Us

XPath: //body[2]/section[2]/div/div/div/p[2]
Text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

XPath: //body[2]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/h2
Text: Our Services

XPath: //body[2]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/ul[2]
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/ul[2]/li
Text: Web Design

XPath: //body[2]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/ul[2]/li[2]
Text: Graphic Design

XPath: //body[2]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/ul[2]/li[3]
Text: Content Writing

XPath: //body[2]/footer[3]
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/footer[3]/div
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/footer[3]/div/div
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/footer[3]/div/div/div
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/footer[3]/div/div/div/h3
Text: Contact Info

XPath: //body[2]/footer[3]/div/div/div/p[2]
Text: 1234 Main Street, City, Country

XPath: //body[2]/footer[3]/div/div/div/p[3]
Text: Phone: 123-456-7890

XPath: //body[2]/footer[3]/div/div/div[2]
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/footer[3]/div/div/div[2]/h3
Text: Follow Us

XPath: //body[2]/footer[3]/div/div/div[2]/ul[2]
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/footer[3]/div/div/div[2]/ul[2]/li
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/footer[3]/div/div/div[2]/ul[2]/li/a
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/footer[3]/div/div/div[2]/ul[2]/li/a/i
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/footer[3]/div/div/div[2]/ul[2]/li[2]
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/footer[3]/div/div/div[2]/ul[2]/li[2]/a
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/footer[3]/div/div/div[2]/ul[2]/li[2]/a/i
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/footer[3]/div/div/div[2]/ul[2]/li[3]
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/footer[3]/div/div/div[2]/ul[2]/li[3]/a
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/footer[3]/div/div/div[2]/ul[2]/li[3]/a/i
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/footer[3]/div/div/div[3]
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/footer[3]/div/div/div[3]/h3
Text: Newsletter

XPath: //body[2]/footer[3]/div/div/div[3]/form[2]
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/footer[3]/div/div/div[3]/form[2]/input
Text: 

XPath: //body[2]/footer[3]/div/div/div[3]/form[2]/button[2]
Text: Subscribe
```

Any suggestions how to find exact full Xpath of all the text of a webpage.

I tried but I'm not getting the exact Xpath that we usually get from webpage any approach how to get?

Comment: there are text nodes and element nodes... for all text nodes you can use findElements and "//text()" as XPATH methinks...   The parent may or may not be an element node.